# Magento2 : Show Three Products on Checkout page in Order Summary section

Tags: magento2.3, knockoutjs, checkout-page, knockout, order-summary

I have added 8 products in the cart and now I would like to show three products on **Order Summary** section on Checkout page with a ***Load More*** button. And, if we click on ***Load More*** button, it will show some other products.

See the example demo : https://jsfiddle.net/z9f35ha1/3/

Please review the attached screenshot. It hides all ***li***

[image]

Kindly suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
$(function () {
    x=3;
    $('.minicart-items li').slice(0, 3).show();
    $('#loadMore').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        x = x+5;
        $('.minicart-items li').slice(0, x).slideDown();
    });
});
```

css

```
.minicart-items li{
    display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Padhiyar Gaurang this is not working same issue